# Conditional Statement Applies but Links do not Display

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following cshtml but it will not display the links for edit and delete inside the conditional statement. I have stepped through and it appears that the statement is applying and I get a match when it comes to myself, but I'm not seeing the links in the final result. It's like it ignores what's inside the brackets but steps right through them in debug.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (User.Identity.Name == item.email)
            {
                Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PersonId });
                Html.DisplayText("|");
                Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PersonId });
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Always put them in, but conditionally have an htmlAttribute of "display:none;"

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle My guess is that the Razor engine is interpreting the contents of the if bracket as C#, not HTML. Try wrapping the links in a <text> tag.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre do you have an example of this?

Comment: `@{bool isEmail = User.Identity.name == item.email;
Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PersonId, style= "display: " + isEmail?"block":"none" });//etc}`

Comment: @Tobias I see, will try that route.  It also seems to display if I remove the semi colon and add an @ at the beginning of each line for some reason. Though it's formatted badly.

Comment: Does it work if you add null as the last parameter ? e.g.: `Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PersonId },null)`

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle Yeah, prefixing with @ is the way to go. :)

Comment: Why won't it show the | part?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as Tobias has mentioned. Your code inside the if-statement is recognized as C# instead of HTML. Remove the semi-colon and add an @ in front of each of the statements and they should render properly.

```
@if (User.Identity.Name == item.email)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PersonId })
    <text> | </text>
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PersonId })
}
```

Comment: This will not display as he wants it formatted. The " | " will not be displayed.

Comment: Thank you, It should be corrected now. I was merely focusing on the links as that is the part mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let Razor know those are executable statements. You also aren't using DisplayText properly, it's intended to show the value of a property. Because the pipe is just plain text, wrap it in `<text>...</text>` and just display the literal value.

```
@if (User.Identity.Name == item.email)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("About", "About")
    <text>|</text>
    @Html.ActionLink("About", "About")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this 2 ways.

```
<td>
    @if (User.Identity.Name == item.email)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PersonId })
            |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PersonId })
        </div>
    }
</td>
```

or

```
@if (User.Identity.Name == item.email)
{
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PersonId })
        |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PersonId })
    </td>
}
else
{
    <td></td>
}
```